# how can I autocomplete visual studio code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2019

like this let's say I did write a code just like this Console.Writ but when I write something like that autocomplete doesn't work I have to delete the code and write again?

the question has been solved!

Comment: Like what? Please provide a minimally working example and clarify your question so that we can better assist you. Add a tag to your language of choice as well!

Comment: like this let's say you are writing Console.WriteLine but you stopped in half just like this Console.Wr you need to delete Console.Wr if you want to work autocomplete what I am saying is how to autocomplete without deleting it I know there is a way but I forgot

Comment: Typically you can press “Ctrl+Space” to see autocomplete options if available.

Comment: Thank you it worked

Comment: @lbragile you should write that up as a proper answer

Comment: @ADyson Done, thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the question, OP wanted to know how to see the autocomplete options when typing in the VSC editor.

For example, when they type:

```
console.
```

Nothing was showing up as a suggestion.

## Solution

To see these autocomplete options, most of the time you can simply press `Ctrl + Space`. If options are available you will see them (see below), otherwise nothing will show up.

This example is for NodeJS, but the same applies to any coding language supported by the editor.

[image: Example of autocomplete options]

Image taken [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=vsc%20autocomplete&sxsrf=ALeKk02_vT-CWitZwJvljwKIMwJJ3WJr0g:1605136658229&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjvotGC0PvsAhWSoFsKHXCZBMwQ_AUoAXoECBEQAw&biw=1920&bih=1007#imgrc=TGDSsS3e6CtaJM)!